# A mean of temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

The problem I’ll be talking about is this one from Callen’s fourth chapter:

> Two bodies of equal calorific constant $C$ are initially at temperatures $T_1$ and $T_2$. We have a reversible work source. Find the maximum work done when reaching thermal equilibrium and the maximum and minimum temperatures of equilibrium.

My doubt is not about how to solve the problem, but about the results for the equilibrium temperatures:

$$
T_{min}= \sqrt{T_1T_2}
$$

$$
T_{max} = \frac{T_1 + T_2}{2}
$$

I noticed that the minimum temperature is the geometric mean of the initial temperatures and the maximum temperature is their arithmetic mean, so I wondered if this holds for the case of $n$ systems in thermal equilibrium, and it does:

$$
T_{max} = \frac{T_1+T_2+...+T_n}{2}
$$

$$
T_{min} = \sqrt[n]{T_1T_2...T_n}
$$

My question is: is there some physical intuition behind this result, or it’s just a silly little rule?

I haven’t included my process of solving the problem because I didn’t find it relevant for the question, but I can edit it and include it if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analytical background: Let there be an $n\times n$ matrix $\mathbf M$ whose elements are nonnegative, $m_{ij}\ge0$ and  $$\sum_{i=1}^n m_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^n  m_{ij} =1.$$ Then we call a function $\phi(\mathbf x)$ Schur convex iff for any $\mathbf x; x_i\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\phi(\mathbf {Mx}) \le \phi(\mathbf x).$

For an arbitrary single-variable convex function $g(x)$ defined on an interval $\mathcal I \in \mathbb R$ the function $\phi(\mathbf x) = \sum_{i=1}^n  g(x_i)$ is Schur-convex on $\mathcal I^n$.

The matrix of 2nd partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_i\partial x_k}$ is positive definite iff $\phi$ is Schur convex.

For details, see:
Zylka, Vojta, Thermodynamic proofs of algebraic inequalities; 10.1016/0375-9601(91)91086-S

---

The arithmetic mean - geometric mean inequality on the equilibrated temperatures is a consequence of the concavity $\cap$ of the entropy $S=S(U)$ with respect to internal energy.
$$\frac{\partial ^2 S}{\partial U^2}=-\frac{1}{T^2}\frac{\partial T}{\partial U}<0 \tag{1}.$$

Now let there be $n$ thermodynamic systems that can interact with each other only through entropy (thermal) exchange but otherwise are isolated from their environment. Then the internal energy of any one of them is the function of temperature only, $U_k=U_k(T_k)$, and its entropy is also concave as $\frac{\partial ^2 S_k}{\partial U_k^2}<0$.

The (negative) convexity of this twice differentiable entropy function can also be expressed by Schur's inequality with $m_{ij} = \frac{1}{n}$ in $\mathbf M$ and $x_i=T_i$ and $T_i$ denotes the temperature of the $i^{th}$ body at any instant.. Then $[\mathbf {Mx}]_{ij}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i T_i = \bar T$ and we get
$$ \sum_k S(U_k(\bar T)) \ge \sum_k S(U_k(T_k)) \tag{2}.$$

This inequality (2) can be specialized for several interesting special cases:

**ideal gas**: $U=kT$ and $S=k\ln U$ then substituting this into ineq (2) you get:
$$\bar T = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n T_i \ge \prod_{i=1}^n T_i^{1/n}.$$

**black-body radiation**: $U=kT^4, S= \frac{4}{3} k^{1/4}U^{3/4}$ and $$n\left(\sum_iT_i^4\right)^3 \ge \left(\sum_iT_i^3\right)^4$$

**ideal degenerate Bose-gas**: $U=kT^{5/2}, S= \frac{5}{3} k^{2/5}U^{3/5}$ and $$n\left(\sum_iT_i^{5/2}\right)^3 \ge \left(\sum_iT_i^{3/2}\right)^5$$

**Spin system at high temperature approximation**:$U=-\frac{k}{T}, S=- \frac{U^2}{2k}$ and $$\left(\sum_i\frac{1}{T_i}\right)^2 \le n\sum_i\frac{1}{T_i^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you take bodies with different caloric capacities, and bring them in contact, the final tmeperature is the weighted mean, or, in mathematical terms, the convex combination.

If physicist had developed statistics first, they had been able some hundred years before Boltzmann to conjecture, that temperature is a statistical expectations value of a mix of many different distributions, that, in the limit, converges to the Gaussian with T the expection of kinetic energy.

If you do the temperature equalization by some Carnot process,  you are doing the same thing, but now the convex combination of the individual entropies, that are conserved in adiabatic processes with maximal mechanical energy strored externally.  Thus it's now $\sum_i q_i\log(T_i)= q \log(T)$ , that yields the log of the product.

Answer (score 1):

If all the bodies reach the final temperature $T_f$, the change in entropy of the nth body is $$\Delta S_n=C\ln{\frac{T_f}{T_n}}$$where $T_n$ is the initial temperature of the nth body. The total change in entropy of the system is $$\Delta S=C\sum_n{\ln{{\frac{T_f}{T_n}}}}$$If the process is reversible, the work is maximum and the total change in entropy is zero.  This gives $$T_f^n=T_1\times T_2\times ...\times T_n$$